# get all elements in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im learning Javascript as my application grow and am pretty much starting from scratch i.e im very new to javascript.

**What Im trying to do**

Get value of all selected radio buttons on form

**Psuedo**

1. Get all elements in form assign to array
2. Loop over elements if type is radio and is checked assign to array

**My Code**

```
var elmnts = document.getElementById("makePicksForm");
var lngth = document. getElementById("makePicksForm").elements.length;

for(var x = 0; x< lngth; x++);
var allElmts = elmnts.elements[x]
 if(allElmnts.type == "radio")
window.alert(allElmnts);    
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<form id="makePicksForm">
 <input type="radio" id="picks'.$x.'" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team1'].' "onclick="return disp()"><span>'.$team1.'</span>
     </label>
     <br />
   <br /> <label class="yellow">
   <input type="radio" id="picks'.$x.'"  name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team2'].' "onclick="return disp()"><span>'.$team2.'</span>
   </label><br />
   <br />
    <label class="pink">
    <input type="radio" name="picks'.$x.'" value="draw">
    <span>Draw</span>
    </label><br />';
```

**My Problem**

[image]

I would like to know what am I doing wrong, why is it that variable allElmnts is not defined, any suggestion how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove *semi-colon* after for loop signature as it will not execute statements under loop with loop. Also use code block for enclosing multiple statements under for loop.

```
for(var x = 0; x< lngth; x++)
{
    var allElmts = elmnts.elements[x]
    if(allElmnts.type == "radio")
         window.alert(allElmnts);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** in jquery

```
var allSelectedRadioValue = $("#makePicksForm [type=radio]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(allSelectedRadioValue)
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c283uaog/6/)**